# If $F = (V,E)$ is a group of trees , $h(F) \equiv \mid V \mid \pmod 2 $?

Tags: graph-theory

If $F = (V,E)$ is a group of trees ( or forest ) then $h(F) \equiv \mid V \mid \pmod 2 $  ?
 $h(F)$ is the number of e-even connected components and an e-even connected component is a connected component with a even number of edges

Comment: consider writing the title more informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges. Your proposition is simple to prove once you recall that fact.

Comment: i dont know how  to start...can u give me a tip ?

Comment: @PaulB. Well, it implies that a tree has an odd number of vertices iff it has an even number of edges, and has an even number of vertices iff it has an odd number of edges. Count $|V|$ by summing up the number of vertices in each tree. Modulo $2$, you can forget about the trees with an even number of vertices...